# Google Marker Object With Same Memory Address Failing == Comparison

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

I have some simple code for detecting when a marker is touched. I have a `GPSActivity` class and it holds both `MakerOptions` & `Marker` variables.

When I add this `GPSActivity` to the map I do this:

`activity.marker = _map.addMarker(activity.markerOptions);`

I just add the `Marker` to the map, and then I store what the map created back into the `GPSActivity`.

Later on, I process a touch. I could create a map (dictionary), but because there are so few markers that will be on the map at any time, its cleaner to just iterate them and check for a match.

So I do just that when a marker is tapped (note: `Timber` is just a logger, so pretend its `System.out.Log()`):

private void onMarkerTouch(Marker marker)
{
    Timber.d("Marker Touch");

```
for (GPSActivity activity:_totalActivitiesForToday)
{
    Timber.d("Looking for " + marker + " against " + activity.marker);
    if(activity.marker == marker)
    {
        Timber.d("FOUND IT");
    } else
    {
        Timber.d("Did not find it");
    }
}
```

}

The thing that I dont understand is the comparator is failing. Even though the markers share the same memory address, the comparison is failing. Do you know why? Here is the log that "proves" `activity.marker == marker`.

Why is the comparison failing when the objects have the same memory address? In this case they both had `34f45507` as their address.

Log:

> Marker Touch
>
> Looking for
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker@34f45507 against
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker@34f45507
>
> Did not find it

Comment: Did you try `marker.equals`?

Comment: Yea that works...WHY!?

Comment: How do you compare `String`?

Comment: I guess I'll have to look up the use cases of == vs equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` is a reference comparison. It checks to see if the objects point to the same reference. `.equals()` evaluates to the comparison of values in the object.

Comment: This is correct, but what confuses is me is the memory address is the same. Hence its the same reference. Shouldnt `==` work?